# What is port name of Raspberry pi3?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3

I want to send a string which is "*" to my arduino. I have a java project. and it is working on my computer. (i defined port name "com3")

But after i load my project to Raspberry Pi3, and i tried to send "*", it fails. Please look at my code. My problem is simple, **what must i write instead of com3 for control rasberry pi 3 usb port**

```
SerialPort seri=new SerialPort("COM3");
private void btnBaslatActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

            seri.openPort();

            seri.setParams(9600, 8, 1,0); 
            seri.writeString("*");

    }
```

Comment: Do you use a SUB to serial converter? Have a look for devices `/dev/ttyUSB*`. Maybe this link is helpfuly as well http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection

Comment: I think on the Pi 3 the serial port is predefined as `/dev/ttyAMA0`